# PHP catch all email extract to which email was sent

Tags: php, email, wildcard, cpanel

I am using cPanel catch all feature for email forwarding to my php script It is working fine for my requirements but there is a problem How can I get the wildcard email address to which the email was forwarded (sent).

for example **someone@example.com**  sent email to **other@example2.com** and than that email is forwarded automatically to **myMail@mydomain.com** than how can I get the address

> myMail@mydomain.com

from my php script (Not from Raw message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are you looking for the e-mail adress (from) of the original sender of the email, you should be able to retrieve this information trough the original headers.. search for the envelope-from adress